# nservicebus - multiple endpoints error

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I get this message:

> Host doesn't support hosting of multiple endpoints. Endpoint classes
>   found: foo.bar.Service.Endpoint.PublisherConfig,
>   foo.bar.Service.Endpoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, foo.bar.Service.Endpoint.PublisherConfig,
>   foo.bar.Service.Endpoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null You may have some old assemblies in your runtime
>   directory. Try right-clicking your VS project, and selecting 'Clean'.

I have tried cleaning the project, with no luck. If I close VS and rebuild the solution, it works, once, then stops working again. This is also the only solution I can find online.

What I find strange, is that it seems to say it found the same endpoint twice?

EDIT: I had a look through the bin folder, and the files created. I found these files:

> foo.bar.Service.Endpoint.dll
>   foo.bar.Service.Endpoint.mm.dll

Comparing this to a co-workers bin folder, he did not have the file with .mm.dll, and his works fine. Difference in systems, is me running win8, him running win7. Both on vs2012, and same source code, etc...

When i delete the .mm.dll file, it works and runs, but when rebuilding it appears again.

Comment: Instead of cleaning, delete all files from your output directory.  If VS doesn't know about the reference, it won't automatically clean the output.

Comment: Already tried, closed vs removed bin directory (of -all- projects in the solution as well), then rebuild. Works once, then fails.

Comment: what version of nservicebus?  Later versions don't require you to define an endpoint.  I would check if there is any difference in your configuration of the endpoint.

Comment: Delete mm.dll as part of you post build events till you find a better solution.
I don't have Windows 8, so I dont see the problem

Comment: Configuration of endpoints are the same, same versions of nservicebus, so really only difference is win8... Strange behaviour though, im just deleting the .mm.dll file as part of post build event untill I can find a better solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not NServiceBus but Mighty Moose (ContinuousTests).

MM is creating a filen named [assemblyname].mm.dll in your bin/Debug folder. Disable MM and you should be fine (just pause the MM-engine is not enough).